# Uploading Minecraft PC Bedrock world to Realms for playing on Nintendo Switch

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms, nintendo-account

My son previously played minecraft on PC with the bedrock edition. He now has a Nintendo Switch and is playing on that.

I have created both a Nintendo Account and a Microsoft Account for him, as instructed, and signed up for the Nintendo Family plan. This means he is able to join selected servers and realms.

Now I want to upload the previous world he created on PC to realms, however I am at a complete loss on how to do this?

Does he need a mojang account, besides the Nintendo and Microsoft account? If so, how do I create it such that it is linked to his existing accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you bought a realm under his account? If so it should be visible under the worlds tab on both devices. Edit the realm (click the pen icon) on PC and find the "Replace World" button. Click that and select the PC save file you want to transfer to the switch. [Note: this will replace the world currently on the realm, so if that worlds important you should download it first.]

Once it successfully uploads, go though the same process on the switch, only this time click the "Download World" button instead of the "Replace World" button. This will download the world to switch as a new save file.